# Which form should be used for nationality: German or Germany

Tags: word-usage

In forms, what should I write for nationality fields? The name of country or the word for people of country?

German, English, Iranian vs Germany, England, Iran.

(I need this for listening section of IELTS)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_people_by_nationality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nationality is always a format based on the term used to refer to people hailing from the nation and not really the nation itself.

> - Jamaica - Jamaican
> - Britain - British
> - Yugoslavia - Yugoslavian

The point of nationality is to indicate the country but in a form that focuses on the people and not the concept of the country/nation.

Answer (score 2):

The country itself is Germany, a noun. A person from that country is "a German", a noun. People or objects from that country, or characteristics of that country, are "German", an adjective.

"Germany is in central Europe." I am talking about the country.

"Heinrich is a German." A person from Germany.

"Mercedes-Benz is a German company." "German beer is exported to many other countries." Things from Germany.

So if you are from Germany, your nationality is "German".

Update several years later:

My attention was just directed back to this page by an upvote, and I notice that I didn't actually directly answer the question.

So, following from what I said above: If someone asks you, "What is your nationality?", the grammatically correct answer would be "German".

If someone asks you, "What country are you from?", the grammatically correct answer would be "Germany".

Of course in real life, if someone asked, "What is your nationality?", and you said "Germany", I don't think there would be any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Nationality is an adjective:
He is French, she is English, they are German.

You can say: 'He is a French man, she is an English woman.'  This is because you are saying 'He is a man, she is a woman' and adding their nationality.  ('Man' and 'woman' are nouns, 'English' is an adjective.)

If you say 'He is a German' that could sound a little bit offensive, as if you are saying something negative about that man, because he is German.